# Algorithm to select a property out of a pool

Tags: java, algorithm, classification, ranking

I am writing a program to add a certain property to a column. Basically each cell in that column has a ranked set of possible properties, for example:

Cell 1 -> properties[A,G,F,T,I]
Cell 2 -> properties [G,F,B,Y]
.
.
.
I want to find the most common property for all the cells so that i can apply it to the column as a whole.

Would appreciate any help.
Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about maintaining following [TreeMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html) (it is sorted)

```
TreeMap<String,Integer>
```

for every cell you put all its properties to the map and if collision occurs, increase the reference counter for that property.

When done, take the property(s) with the largest value of references. This would be the most common property(s). You can later retrieve the property shared by at least NUM_OF_CELLS by calling the [ceilingEntry](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html#ceilingEntry%28K%29) method:

```
map.ceilingEntry(Integer.valueOf(NUM_OF_CELLS));
```

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer, actually another dimension came into the equation, each property is ranked, for example property F is 90% ranked, and property A is 10%, so having A occured more than F is not just the case .. i hope i was clear

Comment: then you will need to change the map to be <String,Double> and the Double value will be calculated with weight taken into consideration (sounds like a minor change)

Comment: i dont think i agree with you here, there is a difference between the number of occurrences and the weight, i should keep track of both

Comment: I think you did not understand my answer. I'd elaborate: the calculation of the Double value will be not the "number of occurrences" but "number of occurrences" X "weight". I'm 100% sure that it will work in your case :) (been there, done that)

Comment: thanks for the elaboration, i have done something similar to what you suggested, the results i get are good.